# Travis CI Install perl module with non-perl language

Tags: c, linux, macos, perl, travis-ci

How do you install perl modules on linux and mac platforms on Travis CI when the language is *not* set to perl?  I'm compiling a C program with perl test scripts.

If the language is perl, `cpanm` is available:

```
cpanm JSON
```

Otherwise if the platform is linux:

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-pp-perl
```

But when on mac `cpanm` and `apt-get` are not available. The mac platform has the `brew` command available to install programs but I can't figure out if I need to install a fresh version of perl instead of just a module for the system perl version.

The mac version also has the `cpan JSON` command available, but it hangs to go through an interactive first-run configuration.

Comment: Check https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Installing-to-system-perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @simbabque's comment I installed cpanm to the system perl, then used cpanm to install the perl module and it works:

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | sudo perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
sudo cpanm JSON
```

<strike>I've not yet figured out the easiest way to install locally without using sudo.</strike>

**Edit:** Without requiring sudo, using `local::lib` to setup `$PERL5LIB` paths etc.:

```
# Install modules into ~/perl5 using system perl
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
~/perl5/bin/cpanm local::lib
~/perl5/bin/cpanm JSON

# Add path to ~/perl5 modules to ~/.bashrc
echo '[ $SHLVL -eq 1 ] && eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Good job figuring out local::lib also! :)